# Where do I find documentation for npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, documentation

Where can I find documentation for npm packages?

I'm trying to find the documentation of the npm package [textract](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract). I can see the [README file](https://github.com/dbashford/textract), but I can't find any other documentation, analogous to what's written in RDoc for Ruby libraries. In particular, I was looking for how to set preserve line breaks to true when running it within a program, as opposed to command line. I ended up having to look at how cli.js did it.

I tried running `npm docs textract`, but that just sent me to the GitHub repo.

rubygems.org has a link to the documentation for a given gem, but I couldn't find the equivalent on the npmjs.com page for textract.

(Note for anyone googling: [this page](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is about the Python library of the same name)

Comment: You've already linked to the "documentation," which is in the readme. What are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @mscdex Responded my editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find any other documentation, analogous to what's written in RDoc for Ruby libraries.

That README file **is** the documentation, analogous to what's written in RDoc for Ruby libraries.

> I tried running npm docs textract, but that just sent me to the GitHub repo.

So it did send you to the documentation, as expected.

> rubygems.org has a link to the documentation for a given gem, but I couldn't find the equivalent on the npmjs.com page for textract.

And npm has a link to the documentation for a given module.

The documentation for textract is here - there are 12 screens of docs there:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/textract

Whether or not you are satisfied with the content of the documentation is another matter. If you're not that you should post an pull request with a better documentation.